# How can I build a link to navigate to the parent page inside of a 2sxc app using c# razor templates?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm building an app that lists out careers in a listing and also has a details template.

The pages in DNN are structured like this: Students (parent) > Organize (child)

I want to make a simple link in the details template (c# razor) to point back to the parent of this child page. So when I'm on Organize, make the link point back to "Students"

Looking through the 2sxc template editor, I see that I can get the parent page's ID using: @Dnn.Tab.ParentId but I'm not sure how to construct a link using that ID.

But how can I make a link to the parent page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple thing you can always do is just href="/tabid/nnn" - so

```
<a href="/tabid/@Dnn.Tab.ParentId">Up</a>
```

Based on your description, I am not sure that covers you 100% of the time, but seemed worth pointing out. :)

If you prefer a more "code" approach, use 2sxc's Link.To()...

```
<a href="@Link.To(pageId: Dnn.Tab.ParentId, parameters: "this=403&category=all")">Up</a>
```

[Reference](https://docs.2sxc.org/how-to/dynamic-code/object-link.html)

Comment: Anyway to get it to use the friendly URL in DNN?

Comment: It will, but don't forget DNN uses (unconverts?) a few keywords. So my example above results in /this/403&category=all, but

```@Link.To(pageId: Dnn.Tab.ParentId, parameters: "this=403&that=all")```

will result in /this/403/that/all - 

Is that what you mean?

Comment: if you are not familiar with the various terms DNN "keeps" in the URL, go to PB/Settings, SEO, URL Management/Expressions and have a look at "Keep in Querystring"